# Customize site URL from gcp project

Tags: url, google-cloud-platform, dns

we are trying to deploy a web page on a gcp project. The site is working but the we would like to change the auto generated url to something more user friendly.
The auto generated URL goes something like: dev-dot-project-numbers.uc.r.appspot.com/
Is there a way to customize or change that url?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. That URL looks like one for App Engine, which you can make available at your own address. You need to control your own domain (there are lots of services where you can get one). Then follow the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains to have your App Engine app respond at an address in your own domain.